# Raspbian-Python3.9: ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed

Tags: python, python-3.x, debian, python-imaging-library, raspbian

I'm trying to run a simple code using **PIL** with custom fonts in **Python3.9** in **Raspbian**, but i can't go past this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pi/python/src/mintest.py", line 2, in <module>
    font52 = ImageFont.truetype('fonts/Font.ttf', 52)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 878, in truetype
    return freetype(font)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 875, in freetype
    return FreeTypeFont(font, size, index, encoding, layout_engine)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 196, in __init__
    if core.HAVE_RAQM:
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 70, in __getattr__
    raise ImportError("The _imagingft C module is not installed")
ImportError: The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

This is the minimum code needed to reproduce the error in **Raspbian**:

```
from PIL import ImageFont   
font52 = ImageFont.truetype('fonts/Font.ttf', 52)
```

This is my system info

> Distributor ID: Raspbian
>
> Description:    Raspbian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch)
>
> Release:        9.13
>
> Codename:       stretch
>
> Python 3.9.6

[Output of python3 -m PIL](https://pastebin.com/mEFqEuAp)

I already tried all the answers i saw here.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install libfreetype6-dev` and then reinstalling Pillow.

Comment: As i said, i tried all the answers i found here, and this library was one of them. It didn't work

Comment: Can you simplify the code further by putting a copy of the font in the current directory and just passing its filename to `ImageFont.truetype()` without all the `os.path()` stuff?

Comment: Also can you run `python3 -m PIL` and [edit] the output into your question please?

Comment: @MarkSetchell done, i uploaded the output to pastebin

Comment: You don't have FreeType support installed. Try `sudo apt install libfreetype-dev libfreetype6-dev libfreetype6` and then reinstalling Pillow.

Comment: I already installed libfreetype6-dev (2.6.3-3.2+deb9u2) and libfreetype6 (2.6.3-3.2+deb9u2). But apt can't locate the lib libfreetype-dev that you mention

Comment: The output in Pastebin shows PIL cannot find Freetype so something is missing. I don't have Raspbian to hand, so see if you can find some other Freetype module to install with `apt update; apt-cache search freetype` Also, did you uninstall and reinstall Pillow?

Comment: Also, can you alter the code you show above with `font52 = ImageFont.truetype()` and add in there `import sys` and  `print(sys.executable) `

Comment: sys.executable -> /usr/local/bin/python3.9
font52 = ImageFont.truetype() -> Same error

Comment: Sometimes it helps to to do `sudo apt install pkg-config` as a first step as it is a good helper for packages to find each other.

Comment: There's an issue raised that says to try `apt-get install libjpeg62-turbo-dev` and then try `pip3 install Pillow --no-binary :all:` I have not tried it. https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5818#issuecomment-963309688

Comment: That worked @MarkSetchell Can you post it as an answer? Thank you so much, i had this project stuck since 2021

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally, I would have expected the solution to the issue:

```
The _imagingft C module is not installed
```

to be installing the Freetype library with:

```
sudo apt install libfreetype6-dev libfreetype6
```

---

However, it seems that the solution is:

```
sudo apt-get install libjpeg62-turbo-dev
pip3 install Pillow --no-binary :all:
```

I have no idea why - there is a discussion [here](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues/5818#issuecomment-963309688).